# Let's encrypt, multiple webserver, one certificate

Tags: webserver, nginx, cluster, letsencrypt

Im searching for a long time now.

**What is the best way to share a let's encrypt certificate across multiple webserver ?**

As example for a HA Cluster.

One way i tought about was, to create a "dummy" server which receives the cert/run the ACME robot and copy the needed files to the other machines. Is this the way i should do it ?

**EDIT:**

- How do i do this for wildcard/subdomains ?
- What about services like https://www.sslforfree.com/ ?

**Example application design:**

[image]

Both NGINXs share a "floating ip", when one server die, the other can do the job.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Why not serve TLS on your HA front ?

Comment: @JeanneD4RK i edited my post and added a example application.
Both nginx's share a "floating ip", if one nginx dies, the other does the job. Therefore i need on both the same certificates.

Comment: Have you considered a hardened NFS share?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, the storage and the tranmission is not the problem. I hang on "how do i receive the certificate" on which server should run the ACME Cert bot ?

Comment: As stated above, NFS share, share : cert, key and .well-known

Comment: @JeanneD4RK And how do i receive the cert ? On what machine does the ACME Cert bot run ?

Comment: Both since it"s shared (if you share /etc/letsencrypt/<domain>/live ). You have to consider the shares as common storage more than server-client